# UI Bootstrap Datepicker week numbers

Tags: c#, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

The [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)  component in UI Bootstrap shows weeks which are calculated by (what appears to be) the first Thursday rule.

What I'm trying to do is to align the datapicker list of weeks with the C# implementation of `GetWeekOfYear` which takes one of three formats.

```
CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay
CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek
CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek
```

Is there any way to change either the datapicker control or the C# implementation so that they both match?

For example: if I look at the week numbers for the datepicker for the start of this year (2015) it shows:

```
Week From-To
52   21 Dec-27 Dec
1    28 Dec-3 Jan
2    4 Jan-10 Jan
```

But if I look at these dates using the C# GetWeekOfYear in the format

```
var weekNumber = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTime, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

where dateTime for example is the first day of the above weeks, I get:

```
Week From-To
52   21 Dec-27 Dec
53   28 Dec-3 Jan
1    4 Jan-10 Jan
```

The only option I have set for the datepicker is the

```
startingDay: 0
```

(Sunday as in the C# code above)

How can I get these to match up using the Thursday/4-day week rule?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx

Comment: @Eterm - yes, according to the msdn, the CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek rule for 2015 should give the week 28 Dec-3 Jan a week number of 1 for a starting day of Sunday as per the code above, no?

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned at the bottom they don't conform to the ISO numbering: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx

Comment: @Eterm - well spotted! Write it up as an answer and I will mark it off.